# Private/privacy conscious calendar app for Android (and maybe contact manager) to replace Flock

Tags: android, security, calendar, cloud-service, contact-manager

I just recently found out about [Flock](https://whispersystems.org/blog/flock/) by Open Whisper Systems.  Aaaaaaand then they decided to [shut it down.](https://gist.github.com/rhodey/873ae9d527d8d2a38213)

Flock has these features that I like:

1. The company has a great reputation in the security/privacy field.
2. Secure sync'ing of calendar and contacts.
3. You can pay them for a service or roll your own server.

I didn't like that it **required** a server.  I would have preferred an option for local-only to be in the mix.

Are there any competitors in this market?  I didn't think there were when I stumbled across Flock, and was very excited to hear about it.  I haven't used it yet though, since my intent was to stand up my own server and I never got around to that.

Are there any other secure calendar and/or contact managers for Android out there?

Comment: http://connectionsapp.us/ provides local-only private contact storage; I'm hoping they will add a synching service or synching options also (disclosure: I know and trust the company founder).

Comment: Like DavDroid, https://fruux.com/ is also based on WebDav, but has the additional option to pay to host on their servers.

Comment: That's not what the OP asks: No syncing, no calendar.

Comment: I would consider that competition in the field.  However, the URL no longer works :-/

Answer (score 3):

There is https://davdroid.bitfire.at/what-is-davdroid which is fully Free Software and available in the https://f-droid.org/ app repository and works with any Dav server, including OwnCloud.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I just came across it and thought I'd share. I think [EteSync](https://www.etesync.com) is exactly what you are looking for.

> Your Data, Yours Only.
>
> Secure, end-to-end encrypted and journaled personal information cloud
>   synchronization for Android and the desktop. Currently supports
>   contacts and calendars, with more on the way.
>
> EteSync costs only $14 a year with no hidden fees. Sign up now for a
>   two week free trial. No payment info required!  Alternatively, you can
>   run your own server for free.

it's recommended by privacytools.io

EDIT:
I recommend this app because it's an open source project which does end to end encryption Calendar and contact sync for Android, just like flock used to do.

Comment: You are supposed to tell why. FWIW this could just be a spam message.

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: at the moment there is no iOS app for EteSync `Want an iOS app? Show your interest here.`